# Font Awesome not working with javascript set value

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, font-awesome

Font awesome is not working for me when I try to change the value of an element using a javascript.

Javascript:

```
function onClick() {
    document.getElementById("dicebutton").value='Rolling <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}
```

HTML code for button:

```
<form>
            Bet<br>
            <input type="text" name="bet"><br>
            Chance<br>
            <input type="text" name="chance"><br>
            <h3>Payout: 0.0000BTC</h3>
            <input value = "Roll dice" id="dicebutton" onClick="onClick()" type="button" style="vertical-align:middle"></input>
        </form>
```

Result:
[image]

Notice how the green button spits raw HTML while the top of the website correctly displays the fonts? How can I fix this?

Comment: `document.getElementById("dicebutton").innerHTML='Rolling <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>';`

Comment: When you use `.innerHTML` it will gut out anything that was in that button. If there was another element originally inside that button or an important class so a function can hooks into are now gone. BTW I assume you are doing HTML5, so inputs do not have an end tag `</input>`. A `<button>` would be a better choice (which I thought you had before I took a closer look.)

Answer (score 3):

Use the element.innerHTML = content; syntax if you want to add HTML. ".value" only passes data as a string.

So

```
 document.getElementById("dicebutton").innerHTML='Rolling <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
```

**Edit:**
I just realized you are using an < input > field for your button. This wont work in that case. The only value for an < input > field that you can use to change the button text is value= as you tried. Unfortunately "value" treats anything assigned to it as a string.

Instead of an < input > field, you will need to use an element that you can attach HTML to - for example, an < a > tag, a < button > tag, or simply using a styled div as a button. This will allow you to pass the HTML to it without having to use "value".

Comment: When I change value to innerHTML, the button oddly does not update any text at all when clicked (the id is the same though).

Comment: Updated my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<button>` tag instead of `<input>` and change 
    `document.getElementById("dicebutton").value`
to
    `document.getElementById("dicebutton").innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You must use button instead of input button, then update the content with innerHTML.

Example:

Javascript:

```
function onClick() {
    // you can you "this.innerHTML" too
    document.getElementById("dicebutton").innerHTML='Rolling <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="dicebutton" onclick="onClick()" style="vertical-align:middle">Roll dice</button>
```