# leaflet: Unable to display icon in the button

Tags: javascript, button, leaflet, icons

I'm extending L.Control to create a collapsible attribution. However, I'm unable to display the font Awesome icon in the button.

Here's the code

```js
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/abc123.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="crossorigin=""></script>
```

```js
L.Control.Attri = L.Control.extend({
          onAdd: function(map) {
            var wrapper = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-wrapper'),
                attribution = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-attribution', wrapper),
                button = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'button', wrapper);
            button.type = "button";
            button.style.width = '30px';
            button.style.height = '30px';
            button.style.opacity = '0.5';
            button.style.borderColor = 'grey';
            button.style.borderRadius = '4px';
            button.style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
            button.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-info"></i>';

            wrapper.style.display = "flex";
            wrapper.style.alignItems = "center";   

            attribution.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            attribution.innerHTML = attri;
        
            button.onclick = function(){
              if(attribution.style.visibility == "visible")
                attribution.style.visibility = 'hidden';
              else
                attribution.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
            return wrapper;            
          },
      
          onRemove: function(map) {
            // Nothing to do here
          }
        });
        map.addControl(new L.Control.Attri({position:'bottomright', metric: false}))
```

**Edited:** Added leaflet and fontawesome version, added button.innerHTML

Comment: So what have you tried to do to display the icon? What is going wrong? Do you see any relevant error messages in the browser console?

Comment: Icon is showing when I displayed it with a div innerHTML, browser console did not display any error.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show what you have tried? Your code works as far as it goes, but there is nothing in it to do with either loading Font Awesome (which version?) or setting an icon (which one?) for the button. Lots of things might be going wrong, but without being able to see how you are trying to make it work, it's hard to suggest how to fix it.

Comment: I have included more information of what versions I'm using and the innerHTML for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use other type of html tag instead of 'input'. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335976/font-awesome-not-working-with-javascript-set-value/44336106), input unable to take in innerHTML and button text value will be treated as string. Hence, this is the updated code:

**'button' instead of 'input'**

```js
button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'leaflet-button', wrapper);
```